# How do I interpret the CADO-NFS output for discrete logarithm calculation in GF(p)?

Tags: public-key, discrete-logarithm, factoring

I'm using [CADO-NFS](http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/index.html) to calculate discrete logarithm in a finite field GF(p). The problem is when I type

```
./cado-nfs.py -dlp -ell 101538509534246169632617439 target=92800609832959449330691138186 191907783019725260605646959711
```

as described in the README.dlp file I just can't understand which of the three values (log2, log3, log(target)) is my discrete logarithm result:

[image: output from CADO]

Anyone with some experience with this tool could help me, please? I didn't find anything on the Internet and the documentation that came with CADO say anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ell` is the largest factor of $p-1$, remember the [Sophie Germain prime](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/22232/18298) $p=2q+1$

All below from mail thread of [[Cado-nfs-discuss] DLP](https://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/cado-nfs-discuss/2016-October/000680.html) and well explained with a sageMath code.

> cado-nfs is right, but maybe the printed info is **scarce or misleading**.
>
> Here's a verification script.

```
> sage: p=53236943330228380237618624445646085674945074907141464418703
> sage: ell=46188898894770668459
> sage: target=51415666321640196744601368459935322494639894379132878321944
> sage: logtarget=15315241815410699555
> sage: log2=39557689199984036821
> sage: redlog=ZZ(Integers(ell)(logtarget/log2))
> sage: (GF(p)(2)^redlog/target)^((p-1)//ell) 1
> sage: (GF(p)(2)^logtarget/GF(p)(target)^log2)^((p-1)//ell) 1
```

> cado-nfs only computes the discrete logarithm of elements of GF(p)^*
>   **modulo ell**. And it won't tell you with respect to which base.
>
> So you first have to decide on which generator you want (e.g., 2),
>   rescale logarithms so that this element has log 1, and then make sure
>   that your target has the right log mod ell. Which is equivalent to
>   saying that you have an equality in the subgroup of order ell, or in
>   other words that when you take the ((p-1)/ell)-th power, you get 1.
>
> The last test of the script is the generic way to do pairwise
>   verification of two (x,log(x)) pairs.

Comment: bolds are mine, and I still wonder why they did not put this into the code.

Comment: Thank you very much @kelalaka. Your answer helped me a lot! I also found this other tool https://sourceforge.net/projects/gdlog/ for calculate discrete log in GF(p). I'd like a tool with a more easy way to choose the base but I think CADO it'll be enough.

Comment: @GustavoSchwantz Welcome.

Comment: .. and for those who are not familiar with `sage`? How can it be interpreted in terms of math, please? I.e., base^power % p == target, what is base and what is power? Or how can I calculate it for, e.g., base = 2, given target?